# Kaspersky PURE 3.0 high network usage

Tags: networking, internet, anti-virus, kaspersky

I'm using Kaspersky PURE 3.0 and Windows 7. The **resource monitor** shows that **avp.exe** is consuming a lot of network. Because of this I lose my network data quickly.

The resource monitor report is http://s8.postimg.org/rmo8qmcx1/high.png

Even if I just use internet for 5-10 minutes just doing stuffs like checking mail, I lose about 8MB of data.

How to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. How are you losing data, exactly?

Comment: @joeqwerty I meant that i reach my browsing upper limit soon

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. Do you mean that you're on some kind of metered/limited internet connection?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes. 6 GB/month beyond which speed is reduced.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the process in question is connecting to the internet? The network utilization of that process may all be on the local network.

Comment: @joeqwerty I've added a screenshot of the report in my question. As you can see it is in the **network** tab and avp.exe belongs to kaspersky only

Comment: @NewUser - The process is not actually using your bandwidth.  Your security product is acting like a proxy.  So most of the "traffic" is proxy traffic [see this](http://forum.kaspersky.com/lofiversion/index.php/t33328.html) I was able to find this information within 3 minutes of research.

Answer (score -2):

Basically you do this to prevent the program from connecting to the Internet:

From start menu, search for "Firewall" and select Windows Firewall with Advanced Security

Choose Outbound Rules from the tree at the left.

Choose New Rule... from the menu at the right.

New Outbound Rule Wizard opens. This is really easy now:

a. Select Program as rule type.

b. Select the program's EXE file.

c. Choose Block the connection.

Choose the profile this rule applies to. If in doubt, select all three.

Add the descriptive name (you may want to delete this rule later).

Comment: If I do this won't it affect my protection?

Comment: That depends what process is using the bandwidth, what it's using the bandwidth for, and what else the process does that needs internet connectivity.

Comment: My question is if I do what you've said will it stop **avp.exe** from stop performing its work? i.e scanning downloading stuffs

Comment: It won't stop it from scanning. It may stop it from downloading updates if that's the process that downloads them. Won't hurt to try and see if it gives you what you want.

Comment: Ok. I'll try it

Comment: If he blocks the processes capability of accessing the internet he won't receive signature updates which means he might was well just uninstall the software.

Comment: In a perfect world signature updates would appear on our hard drives magically, but unfortunately we have to download them, and he doesn't want to use the bandwidth to do that. Got to make a sacrifice somewhere, no?